# Geolocation problems when switch GPS on and off

Tags: javascript, html, gps, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

Thanks in advance first.I build a website with an option to lead you to a specific place when you click button "Navigate". Everything works fine on desktop and everything works fine on mobile when GPS of the phone is enabled.

I use the google maps reference and it works just fine:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=myLat,myLng&daddr=targetLat,targetLng
```

I do this on **$('.button').click()**. Not on **$(window).load** or **$(document).ready**. When you click the button, it calls the geolocation functions:

```
function getGeolocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
    } else {
        $('.error-message').html('<p>Your browser does not support this function</p>');
    }
}

function geoSuccess(position) {
    myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    myLng = position.coords.longitude;

    window.location.href = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + myLat + ',' + myLng + '&daddr=targetLat,targetLng';
}

function geoError(){
    switch(error.code) {
        alert('example alert - enable GPS');

        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            $('.error-message').html('<p>User denied the request for Geolocation.</p>');
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            $('.error-message').html('<p>Location information is unavailable.</p>');
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            $('.error-message').html('<p>The request to get user location timed out.</p>');
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            $('.error-message').html('<p>An unknown error occurred.</p>');
            break;
    }
}
```

But the problem comes when the GPS is disabled.

First of all, sometimes, it doesn't enter in **geoError()**. I tried so many times, but the only thing I "found" is that it caches sometimes. Is that possible ?

But the main problem is that, when the GPS is disabled, the "example alert" pops up, then I turn my GPS on and click the button again, it doesn't work again. I have to refresh the page to apply the GPS turn on. I want to avoid that. Does anyone know why is that happening and is there a way to do what I want?

The other problem is when I load my page with GPS turned on. Then I turn it off and click the button. Nothing happens at all. It enter **getGeolocation()**, gets true and then it stops. It doesn't enter getCurrentPosition(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had ever faced the same problem, and final I found the solution. You can change getCurrentPosition to watchPosition, it seems getCurrentPosition cannot recognize when location changes, watch help us do that. Try my solution, hope it helps you :) 
P/S you should settime out: 10000 for watchpostion or getcurrentpostion

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on Android 6.0 and Chrome 59.0.3071.125.

In short: When I start a webapp with *location Off*, I receive a PositionError as expected.

However when I switch *location back to On*, every subsequent call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` or `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` returns same error.

I've tried the same with [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com) and result is exactly the same (they show a snackbar *Google Maps could not determine your precise location*) so I believe that there is no workaround.

There is a similar post on [ionic framework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getcurrentposition-not-working-after-turning-the-gps-off-on-the-device-even-if-it-turned-on-again/20291) - They didn't find a solution either.

To sum up:

Looks like Chrome is checking for location services **on page load and doesn't update the state any more.

So only thing that helps is **reloading the webapp** which forces chrome to check again if location services are available.

---

**Update:**

this is a known bug in Chromium: [672301](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=672301), [721977](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721977).
Workaround is available in Chrome Mobile v59 behind `lsd-permission-prompts` flag.

Answer (score 0):

In your error function, the argument is missing.

```
function geoError(error){
    //code goes here
    }
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error